# -w test on OS X gives command not found error

Tags: macos, bash

I'm writing a bash script which I'm testing on OS X though it will ultimately run on a standard Linux environment and running into a weird error.

I have tests like this in my script:

```
if [ ! -w $BP ]; then
  echo "'$1' not writable"
  exit 1
fi
```

Which seems pretty sane to me and works fine under Linux but when trying to test on OS X I get the following error message:

> startSvr.sh: line 135: [: missing `]' startSvr.sh: line 135: -w:
>   command not found

So is this a case of OS X not supporting the `-w` test or is there some other reason this isn't working for me? e.g. environment

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you don't have a space after the filename, i.e. the line is actually

```
if [ ! -w $BP]; then
```

because that would generate the error you see.

---

*Updated after OP indicated directory name could include spaces*

Suggest changing your code to

```
if [ ! -w "$BP" ]; then
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the exact cause of the problem because the scripts do have the space but it seems some paths cause the problem and some don't likely because of spaces or similar in the path

Comment: Having spaces in directory names in *nix is a great way to cause yourself grief.  Suggest you switch to underscores or something else.

Comment: If you do have spaces, use "$BP" instead (wrap in quotes).